# PHP - How write in a big amount of files with performance on Windows

Tags: php, performance, io

I have a big gzipped file (~15Gb compressed, ~88 uncompressed) and I need to "explode" the content to a large amount of files. For example, if I read the following line :

```
foo    property.content    "I'm the content of the string."
```

I need to create a file named `foo.db` and store inside :

```
property.content    "I'm the content of the string."
```

I've succeed to get that. But i have performances issues. I think is maybe because of the large amount of file. (~31k files created in 60 seconds) but i don't sure. This is why I'm here.

My code is reading each piece of 1048576 bytes (of the gz file with `gzread`) and sort the content in an Array to write all content one time by file. Then, i made a foreach loop to read the content of my cache, open the specific file and write into. For exemple if my cache look like this :

```
$cache = array(
    "file_one" => "property.content    \"I'm the content of the string.\"
                   property.foo    \"I'm the content of another string.\"",
    "file_two" => "property.foobar    \"I'm the content of the another string.\"",
    "file_three" => ...
);
```

The loop make this :

```
foreach ($cache as $file => $content) {

    $filesrc = $file . ".db";
    $fp = fopen($filesrc,"a");
    fwrite($fp,$content."\n");
    fclose($fp);

}
```

With this method, i read ~65Mb and write ~31k files in 60 seconds.
If i read all the content in one file, I wrote ~220Mb in 60 seconds.

There is something to do to improve the performances and create the small files ?
I'm using `PHP 5.5.1` with `Apache 2.4.6` on `Windows` and I'm using `CLI` to this script.

**Edit :** This is a log to get the time profile of each loop, for 131072 bytes of data readed : http://pastebin.com/uRPFfywY

Comment: To find out where your script needs improvement, you'll first need to time the separate sections to see which one(s) need work. Set `$start = time()` at the beginning of each section and echo `time() - $start` at the end of each section. Then post the results here. Seeing times for the ungzipping, reading, caching and writing will give us a hint of where we can help.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net hi, thanks for the answer. I do that and then I will edit my post to put that. But I thing i need to use `microtime()` instead of `time()` to get a good preview.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net Ok, i post the log : http://pastebin.com/Zfd63aJy. I hope it can help you!

Comment: @Alex-Info.net UPDATE : http://pastebin.com/uRPFfywY to get the time between each loop.